# Web Service ASMX parameter show twice and i only need one

Tags: web-services, soap, arraylist, parameters, asmx

I have this code is web service asmx

```
Public Structure AA
    Public Num As String
End Structure

Public Structure Resp
    Public Ret As String
    Public Men As String
End Structure

<WebMethod> _
Public Function RecTab(ByVal dd As List(Of AA)) As Resp
    Dim strucResp As New Resp

    'Do something

    strucResp.Ret = "0"
    strucResp.Men = "Message"

    Return strucResp
End Function
```

When i publish, SOAP 1.1 show AA twice and just need one

```
<soap:Body>
  <RecTab xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
    <dd>
      <AA>
        <Num>string</Num>
      </AA>
      <AA>
        <Num>string</Num>
      </AA>
    </dd>
  </RecTab>
</soap:Body>
```

I try with `Public Function RecTab(ByVal dd As AA) As Resp` but on SOAP 1.1 doesn't show AA, i get this

```
<soap:Body>
  <RecTab xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
    <dd>
      <Num>string</Num>
    </dd>
  </RecTab>
</soap:Body>
```

I need three levels dd, AA and Num, but just once. How i do to get this?

```
<soap:Body>
  <RecTab xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
    <dd>
      <AA>
        <Num>string</Num>
      </AA>
    </dd>
  </RecTab>
</soap:Body>
```